# MVVM navigating event for WPF WebBrowser

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Can anyone guide me on how to trigger MVVM command for Webbrowser in WPF while navigating.

While the code gives me below error while running :

```
Provide value on 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' threw an exception.

XAML <: WebBrowser Name="Browser" Navigating="{Binding Path=NavigateCommand}" > </WebBrowser>
```

The same code works if I use a code-behind method for navigating event.

Request your thoughts on how view model delegate command can be bound to navigating event of WebBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

`WebBrowser.Navigating` is an event, not a command, so you can't bind it to a command implemented by your view model. Instead you'll need to handle the event in your view, and call the view model manually.

Something like this (assuming you have a property in your view called `ViewModel`, that is a reference to the view model for the view):

XAML:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="Browser" Navigating="OnNavigating" />
```

Code Behind:

```
private void OnNavigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.NavigateCommand.Execute(null);
}
```